# Writing a C Macro

Tags: c, macros

I have to write a macro that get as parameter some variable, and for each two sequential bits with "1" value replace it with 0 bit.

For example: 10110100 will become 10000100.
And, 11110000->00000000
11100000->100000000

I'm having a troubles writing that macro. I've tried to write a macro that get wach bit and replace it if the next bit is the same (and they both 1), but it works only for 8 bits and it's very not friendly...

P.S. I need a macro because I'm learning C and this is an exercise i found and i couldn't solve it myself. i know i can use function to make it easily... but i want to know how to do it with macros.

Thanks!

Comment: `#define TWIDDLE_BITS(var) twiddle_bits(var);` Now all you have to do is to implement the function `twiddle_bits(var);`. `:)`

Comment: Yes, write it as a function, or explain why you need it as a macro (e.g. if you've profiled it).

Comment: If you're able to write it as a function, it's a very short step to translate that to a function.  |void foo(int a) { body }| becomes |#define foo(a) body|

Comment: @Josh: Except when that function has local variables.

Comment: Nice question. I thought about it a while, but I think a single-line-macro for this problem - with the limitation of letting the first bit of an odd-length-run 1 - is quite complicated. 
Maybe you should first determine all runs and then look if the length of a run is odd...

Comment: @sbi @Dave I updated the tags to include his `P.S.` remark about it being a self-improvement exercise.

Comment: @KennyTM: Fair enough.  Including the {} in the macro should fix that, however.

Comment: @Josh: Unfortunately that's a gcc extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define foo(x,i) (((x) & (3<<i)) == (3<<i)) ? ((x) - (3 << i)) : (x)
#define clear_11(x) foo(foo(foo(foo(foo(foo(foo(foo(foo(x,8),7),6),5),4),3),2),1),0)
```

This will do the job. However the expansion is quite big and compilation may take a while. So do not try this at work ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define clear_bit_pairs(_x) ((_x)&~(((_x)&((_x)>>1))*3))
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there's two adjacent bit-pairs.  eg consider `10111100` (binary).  The result should be `10000000`, but this algorithm gives `10101000`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define clear_bit_pairs(_x) ((_x) ^ ((((_x)&((_x)>>1))<<1) | ((_x)&((_x)>>1))) )
```

This will work, but it does not pair up. If it finds the consecutive '1' it will just erase. for example 11100000 will become 00000000 because the first 111 are consecutive.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define foo(x) ({ \
    typeof(x) _y_ = x; \
    for(int _i_ = 0; _i_ < (sizeof(typeof(x)) << 3) + 1; _i_++) { \
        if((_y_ >> _i_ & 3) == 3) { \
            _y_ &= ~(3 << _i_); \
        } \
    } \
    _y_; \
})
```

This probably only works in GCC, since it uses inline statements. I haven't tested it, so it probably doesn't work at all. It is your job to make it work. :-)

The nice thing about this is that it will work with any integral type. It also doesn't rely on any external functions. The downside is that it is not portable. (And I realize that this is sort of cheating.)

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? Is this incorrect, or is just because this is cheating, sort of?

Comment: The task is to do it completely with macros, not with functions. You just use the "#define TWIDDLE_BITS(var) twiddle_bits(var); Now all you have to do is to implement the function twiddle_bits(var);" approach.

Comment: @Danvil: Well, not quite. This doesn't use any functions. Technically it is still entirely a macro. It's just not portable, and it's not just an expression.